# Going from AVM2 Bytecode back to Action Script?

Tags: flash, bytecode, avm2

I currently have a .swf file that I decompressed and decompiled.  I have been looking around for tutorials on how to use ABC Bytecode, but I have not found much.  Is there a debugger program that can convert it back to ActionScript 3?

Would flew 2 do this? or Adobe flash projector debugger? or AS3 Sorcerer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i.  You may be using Alchemy decompile. but, Project "Alchemy" is now the Flash C++ Compiler (FlasCC). Adobe Forum, refer to information about it.

> Alchemy is a research project from Adobe Systems that allows compiling
>   C and C++ code to ActionScript Virtual Machine (AVM2), so that it can
>   be run on Flash Player or Adobe AIR. This is achieved by compiling
>   C/C++ code to LLVM bytecode and then translating LLVM to ActionScript
>   3 with inlined AVM2 bytecode, which is then compiled with a
>   specialized ActionScript compiler. The resulting SWF/SWC is
>   considerably faster than normal ActionScript code, but up to 2x - 10x
>   slower than native C++ code.

Alchemy site: [Alchemy](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/alchemy/)
FlasCC Documents: [FlasCC](http://www.adobe.com/devnet-docs/flascc/README.html)

ii. Another way is to use a free swf decompiler.

[Free_SWF_Decompilers](http://bruce-lab.blogspot.co.il/2010/08/freeswfdecompilers.html)